# Using map to reduce in Gun

Tags: gun

I am new to Gun. I have existing code that very effectively reduces an array of objects based on a pattern. I am thinking I should tweak this to run in the context of Gun's .map and return undefined for non-matches. I think I will also have to provide two arguments, one of which is the where clause and the other the properties I want shown on returned objects. I also presume that if I use .on future matches will automagically get spit out! Am I on the right path?

```
const match = (object,key,value) => {
  const type = typeof(value);
  if(value && type==="object") {
     return Object.keys(value).every(childkey => 
           match(object[key],childkey,value[childkey]));
  if(type==="function") return value(object[key]);
  return object[key]===value; 
}
const reduce = (objects,where) => {
  const keys = Object.keys(where);
  return objects.reduce((accumulator,current) => {
    if(keys.every(key => match(current,key,where[key]))) {
      accumulator.push(current);
    }
    return accumulator;
  },[]);
}

let rows = reduce([{name: "Joe",address:{city: "Seattle"},age:25},
    {name: "Mary",address:{city: "Seattle"},age:16},
    {name: "Joe",address:{city: "New York"},age:20}],
    {name: () => true,
     address: {city: "Seattle"}, 
     age: (age) => age > 10});
```

// results in
   [{name: "Joe",address:{city: "Seattle"},age:25},
    {name: "Mary",address:{city: "Seattle"},age:16}]

Further exploration of this resulted in the code below, which is stylistically different, but conforms to the immediate responsive nature of Gun. However, it is unclear how to deal with nested objects. The code below only works for primitives.

```
const match = (object,key,value) => {
    const type = typeof(value);
    if(!object || typeof(object)!=="object") return false; 
    if(value && type==="object") {
        const child = gun.get(object[key]["#"]);
        for(let key in value) {
            const value = {};
            child.get(key).val(v => value[key] = v,{wait:0});
            if(!match(value,key,value[key])) return;
        }
    }
    if(type==="function") return value(object[key]);
    return object[key]===value; 
}

const gun = Gun(["http://localhost:8080/gun"]),
        users = [{name: "Joe",address:{city: "Seattle"},age:25},
        {address:{city: "Seattle"},age:25},
        {name: "Mary",address:{city: "Seattle"},age:16},
        {name: "Joe",address:{city: "New York"},age:20}];

//gun.get("users").map().put(null);

for(let user of users) {
    const object = gun.get(user.name).put(user);
    gun.get("users").set(object);
}

gun.get("users").map(user => { 
    const pattern = {name: (value) => value!=null, age: (age) => age > 20}; //, address: {city: "Seattle"}
    for(let key in pattern) {
        if(!match(user,key,pattern[key])) return;
    }
    return user;
}).on(data => console.log(data));
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes. GUN's `.map` [method](https://github.com/amark/gun/wiki/API#map) does more than what it seems.

Say we have `var users = gun.get('users')`. We can do:

- `users.map()` with no callback acts like a `forEach` because the default callback is to return the data as-is.
- `users.map(user => user.age * 2)` with a callback, it lets you transform the data like you would expect from a `map`, except where:
- `users.map(function(){ return })` if you return `undefined`, it will `filter` out that record.

> WARNING: As of the current time, `.map(transform)` function is currently experimental and my have bugs with it. Please try it and report any you find.

Now we can combine it with some other methods, to get some cool behavior:

- `users.map().on(cb)` will get current and future users as they are added to the table, and gets notified for updates on each of those users.
- `users.map().val(cb)` will get current and future users as they are added to the table, but only gets each one once.
- `users.val().map().on(cb)` gets only the current users (not future), but gets the updates to those users.
- `users.val().map().val(cb)` gets only the current users (not future), and only gets them once.

So yes, you are on the right track. For instance, I have a test in gun core that does this:

```
list.map(user => user.age === 27? user.name + "thezombie" : u).on(function(data){
    // verify
});
list.set({name: 'alice', age: 27});
list.set({name: 'bob', age: 27});
list.set({name: 'carl', age: 29});
list.set({name: 'dave', age: 25});
```

This creates a live `map` that filters the results and locally (view only) transforms the data.

In the future, this is how the SQL and MongoDB Mango query extensions will work for gun.

> Note: GUN only loads the property you request on an object/node, so it is bandwidth efficient. If we do `users.map().get('age')` it will only load the age value on every user, nothing else.

So internally, you can do some efficient checks, and if all your conditionals match, only /then/ load the entire object. Additionally, there are two other options: (1) you can use an in-memory version of gun to create server-side request-response patterns, so you can have server-side filtering/querying that is efficient. (2) if you become an adapter developer and learn the simple wire spec and then write your own custom query language extensions!

Anything else? Hit me up! More than happy to answer.

Edit: My reply in the comments, comments apparently can't have code. Here is pseudo-code of how to "build up" more complex queries, which will be similar to how SQL/Mango query extensions will work:

mutli-value & nested value matching can be "built up" from this as the base, but yes, you are right, until we have SQL/Mango query examples, there isn't a simple/immediate "out of the box" example. This is pseudo code, but should get the idea across:

```

```
Gun.chain.match = function(query, cb){
  var gun = this;
  var fields = Object.keys(query);
  var check = {};
  fields.forEach(function(field){
    check[field] = true;
    gun.get(field).val(function(val){
       if(val !== query[field]){ return }
       check[field] = false;
       //all checks done?
       cb(results)
    });
  });
  return gun;
}
```

```

Comment: Well as it turns out doing a map to filter with a pattern is pretty straightforward for primitive values. The challenge seems to be matching against nested objects.

Comment: mutli-value & nested value matching can be "built up" from this as the base, but yes, you are right, until we have SQL/Mango query examples, there isn't a simple/immediate "out of the box" example. This is pseudo code, but should get the idea across:

```
Gun.chain.match = function(query, cb){
  var gun = this;
  var fields = Object.keys(query);
  var check = {};
  fields.forEach(function(field){
    check[field] = true;
    gun.get(field).val(function(val){
       if(val !== query[field]){ return }
       check[field] = false;
       //all checks done? cb()
    });
  });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Solution, the trick is to use `map` and not `val`:

```
Gun.chain.match = function(pattern,cb) {
            let node = this,
                passed = true,
                keys = Object.keys(pattern);
            keys.every(key => {
                const test = pattern[key],
                    type = typeof(test);
                if(test && type==="object") {
                    node.get(key).match(test);
                } else if(type==="function") {
                    node.get(key).map(value => { 
                        if(test(value[key])) { 
                            return value; 
                        } else { 
                            passed = false; 
                        } 
                    });
                } else {
                    node.get(key).map(value => { 
                        if(value[key]===test) { 
                            return value; 
                        } else { 
                            passed = false; 
                        } 
                    });
                }
                return passed;
            });
            if(passed && cb) this.val(value => cb(value))
            return this;
        }
        const gun = new Gun();
        gun.get("Joe").put({name:"Joe",address:{city:"Seattle"},age:20});
        gun.get("Joe").match({age: value => value > 15,address:{ city: "Seattle"}},value => console.log("cb1",value));
```